# Should it be ice cream or ice cream's

Tags: possessives, attributives

Should it be...
Using heavy whipping cream will make the ice cream’s texture creamier
                            OR
Using heavy whipping cream will make the ice cream texture creamier.

Is there another way to word this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it's confusing because "ice cream" is two words.  As a counter example, suppose there is just one word:

> Using heavy cream will thicken the **soup('s)** texture.

Here the possessive *soup's* may be more natural; however, as FumbleFingers mentions, the compound noun *soup texture* is not wrong.

In the end it's really a question of which sounds better to you.  Personally, I would either go with the possessive *ice cream's*, or rephrase the sentence.

Answer (score 5):

You can use either *the ice cream texture* or *the ice cream's texture* (and you can hyphenate to *ice-cream* if you want; both orthographies are fine).

If you *don't* include the possessive (and [most people don't](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20ice%20cream%20flavor%2Cthe%20ice%20cream%27s%20flavor&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20ice%20cream%20flavor%3B%2Cc0)), you're actually using the word(s) ***ice-cream*** as a [***noun adjunct***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) (a noun functioning as a pre-modifier in a noun phrase). This is perfectly natural in English.

To avoid the problem completely, you could always rephrase to ***the texture of the ice-cream***. But it's not really a "problem" anyway.

Comment: I suspect most uses of "ice cream flavor" are things like "what ice cream flavor do you want?" where the possessive is not possible.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: True. I did actually think about that when I first created the chart, but what with fiddling about to change from ***texture*** to ***flavour*** (and then ***flavor***, because there are more AmE texts), I somehow lost the leading article for the link I ended up using. Anyway, I've updated it to ***the** ice-cream['s] flavor* now. Not that it makes any real difference - the apostrophised version is always too uncommon to show on the charts, which was my only reason for having a link in the first place..

Answer (score 0):

### Use the *'s* version

You are talking about the texture of the ice cream. By using *ice cream's* you are indicating possession. That is, the texture is that of (belongs to) the ice cream.